# Having issues with Map Activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

About 2months ago, I developed a simple GPS location indicator using google map template in Andriod Studio. I went back to improve but it does not compile.

There was update in android studio when ran general app update in my ubuntu.

The error point to function
**findFragmentById(R.id.map);**
It says,
"cannot dereferenced an int"

What could be done please.

I tried creating new project, then I noticed the map activity template was not among existing templates,  it has been removed.